# How to get camera feeds in Windows 8 Metro style app?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am trying to get camera feeds in Windows 8 metro style app so that i can make some changes on it something like augmented reality. I have tried but only able to find how to capture images using CameraCaptureUI(). Can anyone tell me how can i achieve camera feeds for AR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is pass in CameraCaptureUIMode.Video for CaptureFileAsync. Here is a sample

```
CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
dialog.VideoSettings.Format = CameraCaptureUIVideoFormat.Mp4;

StorageFile file = null;
file = await dialog.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Video);
if (file != null)
{

    IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await   file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
    //Do something with the stream
}
```

**EDIT:**

In order to apply effects you can use the AddEffectAsync method, for example.

```
mediaCaptureMgr.AddEffectAsync(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview, "Microsoft.Samples.GrayscaleEffect", null);
```

The Microsoft Foundation Transform (MFT) implementation of the GrayScaleEffect is [here]. [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That example should allow you to create your own effects.

Comment: Yes with this i can apply effects but cannot implement AR. I actually asked for camera feeds on which i can manipulate and implement AR effects.

Comment: MediaCapture.AddEffectAsync is what you are looking for. It was used in one of the dev preview samples to add grayscale effect.

Answer (score 1):

I [blogged about it before](http://blog.onedevjob.com/2012/01/22/displaying-webcam-preview-in-a-metro-app-using-winrt-and-xaml/).

You need to use a CaptureElement and a MediaCapture object:

```
var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture(); 
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(); 
this.captureElement.Source = mediaCapture; 
await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

Comment: The link is not available anymore