# Windows 8 Metro C# Camera

Tags: windows-runtime, webcam, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a problem with web cams in Win8 metro.
I want to make an application that will draw on photo.source video from webcam. 
Unfortunately, I found only this [How to get camera feeds in Windows 8 Metro style app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9469011/how-to-get-camera-feeds-in-windows-8-metro-style-app) and app opens only capture and I need show only the webcam. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? [windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac/sourcecode?fileId=43599&pathId=1382670463)

Comment: Posting answers that are nothing more than a link is discouraged.  If you could somehow summarize the post, that would go a long way to improving this answer.

Comment: Brianswer, you didn't elaborate on the link, so I cannot upvote your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [CaptureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement.aspx) to integrate the camera feed in your application. In XAML:

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="capElement" Width="400"></CaptureElement>
```

In code-behind, you need to activate the source:

```
MediaCapture captureMgr = new MediaCapture();
await captureMgr.InitializeAsync();

capElement.Source = captureMgr;

await captureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();
```